# On hover change base element using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="hdr-me">Me
  <span class="mearrow"></span>
</div>
```

css

```
.hdr-me {
    width: 33px;height: 28px;float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.47, 0.435, 0.97);
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.47, 0.435, 0.97);
    -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.47, 0.435, 0.97);
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.47, 0.435, 0.97);
    transition-transition:all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.47, 0.435, 0.97);
    margin:9px 5px 5px 5px !important;
    padding:12px 0px 0px 7px;
    background:$blueDark;
    border-radius: 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    color:$white;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.hdr-nav-rt .hdr-me .mearrow{
float: left;
margin-left: 21px;
border-left: 3px solid transparent;
border-right: 3px solid transparent;
border-top: 3px solid $white;
margin-top: -6px;
}
.hdr-nav-rt .hdr-me:hover {
    width: 33px;height: 28px;float: left;
    margin:9px 5px 5px 5px !important;
    padding:12px 0px 0px 7px;
    background:$grayDark;
    border-radius: 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    color:$white;
    cursor:pointer;

}
```

I need to change mearrow also on hover 
like

```
 .hdr-nav-rt .hdr-me:hover .mearrow{
   float:left;
   margin-left:21px;
   border-left:3px solid transparent;
   border-right:3px solid transparent;
   **border-bottom:3px** solid #fff;
   margin-top:-6px;
    }
```

IS it possible using only css

**EDIT**

Both mearrow styles also displaying , both shape are displaying after hover

Comment: Use a `:hover` pseudo-selector, like you did in the example.

Comment: What you have posted should work

Comment: i tried ,it is working but cant able to hide the first me arrow,i mean both are displaying

Comment: on hover i am changing the size of mearrow ,after hover it should be reverse

Comment: sorry  .....i got the answer ,just we need to give border-top:0px

Answer (score 0):

:hover generally works best on anchors. I'd suggest putting an anchor inside .hdr-me and changing the css accordingly. So basically you'd have:

```
<div class="hdr-me">Me
  <a>
    <span class="mearrow"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Then your CSS becomes:

```
.hdr-nav-rt .hdr-me a:hover .mearrow
```

The '.mearrow' will have the hover event triggered for it also this way.

Comment: `:hover` isn't reserved for anchors, it should work fine with spans.

Comment: Not for older IEs. I gathered the original author had been using IE

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Styles to sub-blocks separately. The inner Div will take the style of its own and it will not be overridden by style of parent div.

Find the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/jeSQN/1/).

/* Style for Parent div */ 
    .hdr-me {

```
}
 /* Style for Parent div on Mouse hover*/ 
.hdr-me:hover {

}

/* Style for child div */    
.hdr-me .mearrow{

}
/* Style for child div after on mouse hover*/    
.mearrow:hover {

}
```

Comment: Thanks ,but mearrow is not changing in you fiddle when hovering the parent

Comment: thanks ,i got the answer ,i need to give border-top:0px ,any way thanks